# Can I open a Disk2vhd created VHD file with 7-zip?

Tags: backup, vhd, 7-zip, disk2vhd

I've created a VHD file of my C: drive, for backup purposes, using [Disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) 1.0.

When I try opening the file using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) 4.65 (to view the contents) I get the error: "Can not open the file XXX as an archive".

Does anyone know why this is? I have to assume that either the VHD creation failed and it's a corrupted file, or Disk2vhd creates a variation of the VHD format that 7-Zip doesn't support.

Comment: Not an answer to my question, but this looks useful: http://discutils.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Windows 2008 Server R2, and it supports mounting VHDs as drives from Computer Management\Storage\Disk Management. Win7 probably does the same.

Here's a fun script to mount it from the Windows Explorer menu:
http://www.howtogeek.com/51174/mount-and-unmount-a-vhd-file-in-windows-explorer-via-a-right-click/

Carl

Answer (score 1):

You can open VHD files with 7-zip 9.20 x64, under Windows 7. It seems this functionality has been present since 9.04, so it wouldn't have worked with the version you mention.

As mentioned above, Windows 7/Server 2008 R2 supports mounting VHD files as drives through the Disk Management snap-in. This can be accessed by selecting **Attach VHD** on the aforementioned MSC.

Comment: This doesn't answer the author's question in the slightest. The only helpful bit is the fact you mention you can attach the VHD image within Windows 7's Disk Management of course the author already knew this.

Comment: @Ramhound: It seems like a perfectly reasonable answer to me. What am I missing?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg It appeared to me, to be more of a comment than an answer.  However now that I've read it in more detail I agree with you.

Comment: @Ramhound Unfortunately, I'm a bit of a master of circumlocution and hide answers in walls of text. I could pare it down a bit, if you wanted?

Comment: @Jeeva - Make some sort of modification and I will remove my downvote.

Comment: I only added my answer to answer the title question for future searches (as I got here on a slightly unrelated note). Happy to make it more obvious, though.

Answer (score 0):

As noted [here](http://www.gilsmethod.com/how-to-mount-vhd-files-without-virtual-pc), the program [GizmoDrive](http://arainia.com/software/gizmo/overview.php?nID=4) (freeware) can be used to mount vhd files as a virtual drive.

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 so I can do this through the Disk Management utility anyway, but I think I read that it's not a good idea if the VHD is an image of the system you're currently booted into.

Answer (score -3):

I think the only way to get the contents from your .vhd file is to actually boot it up with a Virtual PC or from a hyper-v server.

I don't believe it is in any sort of backup archive format (but I'm willing to be corrected).

Comment: I've opened .vhd files created by other applications using 7-Zip, it's quite handy and definitely possible. For example, the ones created by the Windows Vista Complete PC Backup.

Comment: Interesting! And those backup VHD files are known to be the same format as virtual PC VHD? I was completely unaware :-)

Comment: Yep, more information on the format here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHD_(file_format)

Comment: I said "willing to be corrected" not down-voted w/out comments :-p